# Org-mode initial visibility: show each top heading's direct children only

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to achieve this visibility on startup:

```
* Top 1
** Sub 1.1...
** Sub 1.2
* Top 2
** Sub 2.1
** Sub 2.2...
** Sub 2.3
* Top 3
** Sub 3.1
```

That is, all top level headings should show their direct children. Not more and not less (I'd accept it if property/logbook drawers were visible, but optimally, I'd like them hidden). Is this possible using startup visibility (per-subtree) properties or anything else? It is achievable interactively by (starting form a folded view) selecting each top heading and pressing `Cc TAB`. I'm actually curious if this is something no one is missing in the default possibilities, or whether I've just not found it.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139561/open-a-org-file-with-specified-depth-of-headings) help?

Comment: Kind of, yes. Thanks a lot!